# Build querystring automatically to send form via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I need to send a complete form via ajax to prevent the refresh of the complete page. Since the  form has a huge number of inputfields, i dont want to build the querystring manually. I found some scripts collecting all elements in the form and building the querystring automatically. But is there any easier way to build the query string automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using serialize() method of your jquery form wrapper object !

see : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).
Example from jQuery site

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.serialize` to serialize all input fields in the form. Try below script and alert the value,

```
   var formValues =  $('form').serialize();
   alert(formValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the info in your page and send it in a query string to another page right??

you could simply add the Previous page Type directive in the page you're redirecting to, and add properties in your first page to return the values in the controls and call it using previous page property 
refer to [this](http://mohamedelkhodary.blogspot.com/2012/03/use-previouspagetype-to-simplify-page.html) article

Comment: What from the javascript, jquery, ajax, forms and post tags gave you the impression he's using ASP.NET?

Comment: sorry that was my bad, I must have conflicted it with something else